# android sqlite database path.in real device

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing a cordova based mobile app in android , and trying to get the database path in real device.Please help. Not getting path in (file explorer -> data -> data -> see your package name -> databases )

Answer (score 1):

```
data/data/<packagename>/databases/
```

Here's a sample you can use with adb to see the files

```
adb shell ls -al data/data/us.raddev.quotecap/databases
```

Depending upon how you are attempting to view that location you will not be able to see it.  For example, if you are attempting to use the ESFiles app you may not be able to see the data unless the device is rooted.
Cordova may not be able to list the files in that location. Not sure.